# Spaces in Arguments for discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to tweet messages from discord.js, but whenever i tried to tweet a message with spaces i get "hello,from,discord" instead of "hello from discord"

````
const Twitter = require('./twitter')
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim();
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'tweet') {
        Twitter.makeATweet(args)
        message.channel.send('Tweet The Message Go to https://twitter.com/Epic_Meme_Bot to check it outer');
    } else if (command === 'beep') {
        message.channel.send('Boop.');
    }
    // other commands...
});

client.login(token);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're tweeting the arguments of the message, which means it gets split at the   (space) in the message.

Your argument handling is also slightly incorrect, you probably want to add `.split(" ");` to the end of `args` like this:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

A fix to put the whole message as a tweet would be:

```js
Twitter.makeATweet(message.content);
```

However, if you want to ignore the command you can rejoin `args` with a space, like this:

```js
Twitter.makeATweet(args.join(" "));
```

Comment: IT WORKS THX SO MUCH

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it is working to help other users

Answer (score 0):

As Pentium said, that's because the arguments is an array of strings, and you're trying to turn that into a string, which would result in all of the elements inside the array being separated with commas. To avoid this, you can use the `.join()` method

```js
Twitter.makeATweet(args.join(" ")) //this would separate all the arguments with a space
```